# blacklisting mac address on my router to “isolate” IP cameras?

Tags: security

I currently have two very cheap Chinese IP Cameras. I just discovered they are vulnerable to attacks and as you can expect there are not patches by the provider.

My final goal is to isolate them with a router or managed switch with VLANs but I don't have knowledge about vlan yet and I don't have a router and managed switch with VLAN capabilities yet.

Meanwhile, I found that my current router has a firewall which can block MAC addresses accessing the internet. I have blocked these IP cameras by using this. I tested if it worked by trying to remote view them and they can't viewed with the blacklisting on.

My question is whether there are shortcomings using this? Are the cameras still vulnerable now that they are blocked from any internet access? Maybe I don't even need VLAN now?

Would be glad to hear your feedback on this. Thx

edit: the passwords of these cameras are publicly known; there's a backdoor default account.

Comment: Are these IP cameras vulnerable through a given protocol (like `telnet`, `snmp`… or only or through their default password which is publicly known? •••• Please add these useful details within your OQ.

Comment: their passwords are publicly known; there's a backdoor default account.

Comment: 1st thing: change this password ASAP. If the protocol used to attack them is `telnet`, block it fully ( = `from ip any` ) on your router.

Comment: yeah I changed the password of my account but there is a backdoor default account that can't be deleted or modified. with the MAC blacklisted, one of the cameras can't even be accessed on local LAN (how is that possible? it was routing through the internet to work?)

Comment: Security by MAC address is foolish as it is very easy to change the MAC address on a device. In any case, we really have no information about your network. Please edit your question to include a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. The real solution is to replace the vulnerable devices (cameras) on your network.

Comment: Welcome on StackExchange. Does your router have many Ethernet ports? Does it manage DHCP, NAT or VLANs? •••• Please add these useful details within your OQ. Without these minimum information you can only expect fantasy answers.

Comment: I will quote my post "My final goal is to isolate them with a router or managed switch with VLANs but I don't have knowledge about vlan yet and I don't have a router and managed switch with VLAN capabilities yet."

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking Internet access at the router isn't enough as a compromised camera can still do a lot of damage in your network. The camera/device doesn't necessarily be attacked directly from the Internet, it's possible to exploit vulnerabilities through other attack vectors (other compromised hosts, cross-site scripting, ...).

VLANs are the way to go. They allow you to isolate untrusted devices in your network. The different VLANs are connected by a firewall, router or L3 switch that allows you to control all traffic between the VLANs and to/from the Internet.

On the firewall, router, or L3 switch you'd use ACLs or policies to define the permitted traffic, blocking everything else.

Comment: I understand that VLAN isolate untrusted devices from my network but I still need to communicate with these devices (ex. my NVR) ...so I will need to allow communication between the cameras and the NVR (NVR is connected in my main network). if you say the camera can damage my network.... can't it still do it through the NVR even if it is in a separate VLAN?

Comment: That depends on how everything is connected and how the NVR or a router is set up.

Comment: In Zac's answer, he suggests you *use ACLs or policies to define the permitted traffic, blocking everything else.*  In other words, once you have all the vulnerable cameras on their own VLAN, identify the type of traffic you need to exchange between the camera VLAN and any others (such as a security DVR or workstation), and allow only that traffic to/from the camera VLAN.  Block everything else.